# Function added on link with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to create multiple html links to use as buttons. I am creating 15 at the moment, and in the future I might need to add more, so I want to do that through JS. The following code adds the objects on the screen, but the buttons don't do the function assigned. In fact, they don't do anything at all, they just go to index.html#.

```
function buttonCreate(){

var element = $(".left");

for (i in upgrades){
        a = $('<a>',{
        text: i,
        href: '#',
        id: i
    });
    var upgrade_button = $('#' + i);
    upgrade_button.click(function(){upgrade(i);return false;});
    a.addClass('myButton');
    a.appendTo(element);

    para = $('<p>',{
        text: "",
        id: i+"_upgrade"
    });
    para.appendTo(element);

    para2 = $('<p>',{
        text: "",
        id: i+"_income"
    });
    para2.appendTo(element);
    document.getElementById(i+"_upgrade").innerHTML = "You need " + Math.round(upgrades[i].cost).toLocaleString() + " to upgrade " + i;
    document.getElementById(i+"_income").innerHTML = "Next " + i + " give " + Math.round(upgrades[i].income).toLocaleString() + " passive income";

    }
}
```

I have also tried adding the function directly to the freshly created link element.

EDIT:

I am giving you the upgrades var and the upgrade function:

```
var upgrades = {
'A': {
    cost: 100,
    income: 10
},
'B': {
    cost: 1000,
    income: 100
},
'C': {
    cost: 10000,
    income: 1000
};
```

And the function:

```
function upgrade(type){
if ((points - upgrades[type].cost) >= 0) {
    points -= upgrades[type].cost;
    upgrades[type].cost *= upgrade_incr;
    pincome += upgrades[type].income;

    clearInterval(intervalVar);
    intervalVar = setInterval(function(){pas_incr(pincome/8);},125);
    //upgrades[type].income *= val_incr;

    display = Math.round(points).toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = "Points: " + display;
    document.getElementById(type+"_upgrade").innerHTML = "You need " + Math.round(upgrades[type].cost).toLocaleString() + " to upgrade " + type;
    document.getElementById(type+"_income").innerHTML = "Each " + type +" gives " + Math.round(upgrades[type].income).toLocaleString() + " passive income";
    document.getElementById("pincome").innerHTML = "You have " + Math.round(pincome).toLocaleString() + " passive income";
    }
}
```

The fact that I am using both JS and Jquery is that I just learnt jquery, and started implementing that. As a note, I couldn't get it to work with simple JS either.

Comment: Post your markup also

Comment: Your code has too many unexplained variables. What are `upgrade` and `upgrades`? Have you tried investigating your HTML with your browser's element inspector? Have you tried adding a `debugger;` breakpoint to your function calls, to figure out what goes wrong? Like so: `upgrade_button.click(function(){ debugger; upgrade(i); return false; });`?

Comment: `i` does not retain its value when the events occur. Your call to `upgrade(i)` will pass the final value of `i`. Also, if you are going to use jQuery at all, use it to reduce the amount of code and not use `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Thank you guys. The solution below solved my problem, as well as a couple more questions. Also, I will make everything jQuery, but I haven't got to it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to query your button before inserting it into the DOM (`upgrade_button`). But you already have the button in your local scope (`a`). Simply add the `click` property during button creation.

Instead of:

```
   a = $('<a>',{
        text: i,
        href: '#',
        id: i
    });
    var upgrade_button = $('#' + i);
    upgrade_button.click(function(){upgrade(i);return false;});
```

Try:

```
   var a = $('<a>',{
        text: i,
        href: '#',
        id: i,
        click: function(){upgrade(i);return false;}
    });
```

**UPDATE**

As [TrueBlueAussie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201078/trueblueaussie) states in the comments, you cannot use `i` in your `click` closure because it will assume the final value of your `for loop` at the point in time when `click` is actually called.

New version:

```
   var a = $('<a>',{
        text: i,
        href: '#',
        id: i,
        click: function(){ upgrade(this.id); return false; }
    });
```

Comment: Good catch -1 removed :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks for the catch. However, my solution still fixes his original bug (`click` not being called at all). So technically, it still answers the question. You are a quick down-voter :p

Comment: And a quick *un*-downvoter when things are corrected :P You have to solve the whole problem.

Comment: As it happens a delegated event handler would be more appropriate for the problem outlined (but the code also needs a lot of cleaning up).

Comment: I was thinking the same. Should you really get downvoted for not fixing all problems included in questions, even such unrelated to the question itself? I guess if you include that broken code in your answer, maybe.

Comment: @Peter Herdenborg: IMHO an answer is a *complete answer* to the *entire problem*, not just parts of the problem. Many partial answers should be comments instead. :)

Comment: Then I'll think twice before answering when I see you online ;) Agree that comments and helpful partial improvements posted as answers deserve downvoting.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem as well as answered a couple of my questions. Precise and effective.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `var upgrade_button = $('#' + i);` before the element has been inserted into the DOM tree, so jQuery won't be able to look it up using the ID selector like that. Thus `upgrade_button` doesn't represent anything when you attach the click handler to it.

Also, `upgrade_button` will be identical to the `a` variable, so you can scrap it completely and just use `a` instead.